# DNSSEC implementation questions (BIND 9.10)

Tags: dns, dnssec

I am planning to sign multiple DNS zones with BIND and have the following questions which I could not answer by reading the latest [BIND 9.10 Reference Manual](http://www.bind9.net/arm910.pdf).

1. How can I use the same ZSK with multiple zones? When generating a new key with `dns-keygen name` seems to offer `-n nametype` where `nametype` can be one of `ZONE, HOST, ENTITY, USER, OTHER`. Can one of them be used to associate the generated ZSK with a set of zones?
2. Where can I specify what directory the signed zone files (`*.jbk, *.jnl, *.signed, *.signed.jnl`) get put into when using `inline-signing yes;`? I'd rather have the directory with the original zone files (which get edited manually) rather clean and put the auto-generated files somewhere else.

Since I am not sure whether or not "Stackexchange - Information Security" is also intended to be used for specific implementation questions, please move the question if it doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1 (Same ZSK):

You should not use the same ZSK for multiple zones (as far as I know), as it is a **zone** signing key. There should be one ZSK for every zone.

#### 2 (Journal Files):

You cannot move the journal files with the current version of bind, however you can make the zone files in the directory bind uses symlinks to files in a cleaner directory.

Comment: Why shouldn't you sign multiple zones with the same ZSK? Deriving this policy from the name seems a little far-fetched...

Comment: Especially since OpenDNSSEC seems to be able to do exactly that.

Comment: Sorry, it appears that it is possible to use the same ZSK for multiple zones (I was under the impression you couldn't). However, it is recommended that you don't: https://users.isc.org/~jreed/dnssec-guide/dnssec-guide.html#same-key-for-multiple-zones